# Should I maintain any minimum distance between two hall encoders of two motors?

Tags: dc-motor, encoder, hall-effect, rotary-encoder

I am a beginner and am trying to build an autonomous mobile robot. I want to use two DC motors with Hall-effect encoders. The image shows the position of the two DC motors.

Do I need to maintain any minimum distance (for example, 1/2 inch or 1 inch) between these two motors so that one motor does not affect the Hall encoder of another motor?

I am using a [Pololu 25Dx69L](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1829/pololu-25d-metal-gearmotors.pdf) 75:1 Metal Gearmotor mm HP 12 V with 48 CPR Encoder.

[image]

Comment: Please link the data sheets of the hall sensors

Comment: The hall encoders come with motors. I have added the motors' datasheet.

Comment: Off the top of my head I would think 1/2" to be fine. Pain to wire up if its closer anyways. Remember the motor has magnets too and the magnetic encoder has its own magnetic disc and works just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2):

There probably isn't anything you need to do, there is nothing in the datasheet warning about noise. Magnetic fields fall off with the cube of the distance so it might be a problem placed back to back. Giving a few cm would be plenty.

Probably the best thing to do would be to buy two motors and place them back to back and see if they get interference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and suggestion.